# JavaFX Application class not in javafx.application package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, javafx-11

I recently have updated Eclipse to version 2019-12 and my JDK to Java SE 13, and I learned afterwards that this JSE no longer includes JavaFX as a core library. So, I looked up the Maven dependency entries for newer JavaFX libraries compatible with JSE 13 and picked version 11. I added them to my `pom.xml` file as such:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>...</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <url>https://github.com/.../url>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        ...
        <!-- JavaFX is no longer included in JDK --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
           <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
           <version>11</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However, now some `javafx` imports in my source files cannot be resolved. For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application; //Application class not found
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color; //Color class not found
```

I’ve checked the javadocs for the `javafx...Application` and `javafx...Color` classes, and it appears they should be included among the class files within the `graphics`, `controls`, and `fxml` modules I linked as dependencies in the `pom.xml` file.

Why are my imports not resolving?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh never mind. I was bumbling with this for a couple hours before I tried bumping up to JavaFX 13 in my Maven dependencies and now everything works.

:/